# Logarithm calculation result

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am carrying out a review of a network protocol, and the author has provided a function to calculate the average steps a message needs to take to traverse a network.

It is written as $$\log_{2^b}(N)$$

Does the positioning of the $2^b$ pose any significance during calculation? I can't find an answer either way. The reason is, they have provided the results of their calculations and according to their paper, the result would be $1.25$ (given $b= 4$ and $N= 32$).
Another example was given this time $N= 50$, $b=4$ giving a result of $1.41$.

I don't seem to be able to get the same result if I were to apply the calculation and so it's either my method/order of working or their result is incorrect (which I doubt).

Can someone help to provide the correct way of calculating the values, and confirm the initial results? 
My initial calculation was calculate $\log(2^4) \cdot 32$... Clearly it's totally wrong (maths is not a strong point for me).

Comment: @TMM - thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base of the logarithm is $2^b$. You want to find an $x$ such that $(2^b)^x = N$, i.e. $2^{bx} = N$.

You can rewrite that as $$x = \dfrac{\log N}{b}$$ if you take the $\log$ to base-2.

Comment: @Ollie P.S. the logarithm function `log` provided in many programming languages (C, python, ...) is actually the natural log, i.e. the base-$e$ log, which is usually written $\ln$ on e.g. pocket calculators. In this case what you want is `x = log(N)/( log(2)*b );` Also, in C `log(2)` is a pre-defined constant M_LN2, so you could write `x = log(N)/( M_LN2*b );`

Comment: Got it - when the base was changed to 2 I can get the correct answer from the measurements. I'm still not to sure how you would realise to use base 2...but at least I have the correct data. Thanks so much for the answer - it really helped!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to compute in your given example $N = 32$, $b=4$ is $\log(32)$, in base $2^4 = 16$.

If you are using a calculator, the "log" function often computes $\log_{10}$ or $\log_e = \ln$ of an argument, so your result is likely computing the log with one of these bases.

You can perform a [change of base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base) from $2^b$ to $10$ or $e$ by using the following formula:
$$\log_{2^b} a = {\log_d a \over \log_d 2^b}= {\log_d a \over 2\log_d b}  $$

Where $\log_d$ can be either $d = 10$, or $d = e$, or for your purposes, base $d = 2$.
In the last case, then, where $d = 2$, the given formula simplifies to the equation displayed in Aryabhata nice answer!

Comment: Computer science usually (and perhaps not in this context) uses $\log_2$, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks! - I'm using Excel in this instance for input so I can easily specify the based - however its still a useful answer and much appreciated.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be more helpful :-(

Comment: Well someone will come by who needs to calculate it manually and your highly detailed answer is bound to help them out :) - shame I can't accept both answers...I can't even up vote yet